# What would be the logistics behind evacuating the Western United States?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, science-fiction, logistics

Assume Godzilla rampaged the West Coast in to a fine powder and is moving east, into the western states of the United States (Washington, Oregon, California, Nevada, southern Idaho, and a small bit of southwestern Arizona).

How would the US Government evacuate the 50 million Americans to refugee camps located east of the Rocky Mountains in the Midwest? I'm really interested in the logistical details.

Comment: The Department of Homeland Security has published [some material](https://www.hsdl.org/?collection&id=28) related to mass evacuations.  The National Governor's Association has also published [Governor's Guide to Mass Evacuation (PDF)](https://www.nga.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/GovGuideMassEvacuation.pdf).  Maybe this will be useful?

Comment: You don't know westerners very well.  Most would stay and fight.

Comment: @jamesqf: Most would stay and fight...against the gubmint trying' to steal our laand. This giant lizard is FAKE NEWS

Comment: Scale up the [Rita evacuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Rita#Mass_evacuation). 15 times the people, but ~15 times the highways and other resources available. It takes 10 hours to setup [contraflow lane reversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraflow_lane_reversal) if you have a plan, and you'll note that none of those states have a plan.

Comment: "Godzilla rampaged the West Coast in to a fine powder "..now you want to evacuate the "fine powder"? Just how many people in those regions will have survived Godzilla? How many will have survive the riots, looting , arson, chaos and mayhem that followed? It is almost impossible to evacuate a population *after* a disaster, as the people resist and the transport infrastructure is gone. You ave to evacuate them before it strikes.

Comment: If you've already survived Godzilla, what point is there in evacuating *now*? Sure, there's no infrastructure, but there's no adequate infrastructure in the Midwest either.

Comment: To start such a large-scale evacuation, you would need trillions of dollars in money, resources, and preparation. Not to mention the cost of displacing 50+ million people and dropping them in the midwest which would not be prepared for such a housing boom. Which is not a real solution to the Godzilla problem because who says Godzilla won't just follow everybody? It would be far more practical to devote all that time, money, and resources to kill Godzilla.

Comment: @PcMan: The "West Coast" and the "American West" are two very different areas.  The West Coast is the area between the Pacific Ocean and either the Coast Ranges or Sierra Nevada/Cascade ranges (depending on who you ask).  The "America West" lies between the West Coast and the Rocky Mountains.  The West is large, and most of it is dry and sparsely populated.  Godzilla is going to have to do a LOT of travelling to manage any serious devastation.

Comment: The United States is over 1000miles in cross section.  If Godzilla was marching from the west to the east, 99.9% of the West would not be within a mile of its path.  It would not be sensible to clog the highways trying to escape east.  In fact, that seems like about the best way to lure the monster in to eat you. Better to wait if it gets near, and only those directly in its path should evacuate.

Comment: @Ash Do you have any links for descriptions of where those millions of people went? I interpret the number as '3 million left heir home but might have travelled only 10 miles to the next shelter' - clearing a 10-mile coastal zone would be very much different from clearing a 1000 mile coastal zone as the effects of the linear-square law come to bear (people inhabit area, while egress is only along the border of said area) - As long as Godzilla did not send an rsvp months ahead of arrival, i think there will just be a lot of dying, no plan.

Answer (score 2):

OKAY. So my first thought was to consider what protocol the U.S. has for a Yellowstone Eruption since the supervolcano is in the same region and an eruption would require millions of people to evacuate.

This source: https://pubs.usgs.gov/circ/1351/downloads/circ1351_v2.pdf has all of their PRE planning explained as far as I can tell. Who would be watching, what alerts they give, and such. They have a large team of scientists consistently watching data.

Now, with this theoretical Godzilla attack, that is a direct threat to American citizens right over the border. This leads me to believe it would be a combination of military personnel and the Department of Homeland Security who would work on slowing down Godzilla and attempting to take it out.
[https://www.dhs.gov/about-dhs#:~:text=The%20Department%20of%20Homeland%20Security,analyst%20to%20chemical%20facility%20inspector](https://www.dhs.gov/about-dhs#:%7E:text=The%20Department%20of%20Homeland%20Security,analyst%20to%20chemical%20facility%20inspector).

[This guide](https://www.nga.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/GovGuideMassEvacuation.pdf) to Mass Evacuation by the National Governor's Association highlights some important things.

Firstly, non-governmental organizations would have to be promptly contacted and evacuated with the main population. These include organizations like the Red Cross and the National Voluntary Organizations Active in disaster. These group would help provide evacuees with necessary medial/first-aid treatment and other necessities that such a disaster may create need for.

Secondly, previous to this event, shelters likely will have been created and evacuation plans at least known by those helping aide evacuation. When Godzilla first appears on the American radar, an evacuation order would likely be sent out. The farther people are from the coast, the more likely they are to be more prepared since they will have more time to do so.

The above link says:
Among the basic elements evacuation plans include are the following:
 - Hazards and vulnerabilities that can cause evacuations;

- Decision-making authority;

- Types of evacuations (mandatory or voluntary);

- Clear evacuation terminology coupled with legal implications;

- Interagency and multijurisdictional coordination and communication;

- Specific state agency roles and responsibilities;

- Concepts of operations, including timing of triggers for evacuation;

- Mass care and sheltering capability and implementation;

- Reverse-lane procedures (if necessary);

- Logistical contract support needs (public transit, buses, ambulances); and

- Beneficial mutual aid support agreements with counties, neighboring states, and NGOs.

Other Evacuation things:

1. **Phasing** (page 8): helps get things done orderly. This would likely be done in a situation with more forecasted warning as this takes time.
2. **Contra-Flow Plans** (page 9): allow all roads to essentially be one direction to help speed up the process of outward flow from a place.
3. **Shelter-In-Place** (page 9): when staying home is safer and likely to keep people under better protection than attempting to flee.
4. **Emergency Powers** (page 11): who's in charge during an evacuation/crisis

Pages 13-14 have a list of important legal figures from state to state.

**Alerting systems would include**: television, radio, road signs, texts, and
social media, systems like the Integrated Public Alert and Warning System to push
information out to the public by using them to issue emergency alerts, including wireless emergency alerts,
the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration (NOAA) Weather Radio, and other public alerting
systems

**ON EVACUATION TERMS**

Terms such as “mandatory,” “voluntary,” “partial,” and “recommended” have specific legal implications,
and the precise meaning of those terms varies from state to state. For example, some states have arrest
authority for citizens who refuse to heed a mandatory evacuation. In some states, public safety officials
have a reduced liability to respond to 911 calls during mandatory evacuations. Governors are encouraged
to review terminology and work with FEMA and state, local, and tribal emergency management agencies
to create effective and clear terminology consistent with the National Incident Management System. The
terminology should be phrased in a manner that causes citizens in imminent danger to react quickly.

As defined in the Comprehensive Preparedness Guide 101 (CPG 101):7

- A voluntary evacuation is a warning to persons within a designated area that a threat to life and
property exists or is likely to exist in the immediate future. Individuals issued this type of warning or
order are not required to evacuate; however, it would be to their advantage to do so.

- A mandatory or directed evacuation is a warning to persons within the designated area that an
imminent threat to life and property exists, and individuals must evacuate in accordance with the
instructions of local officials.

Here is a source for a more personal civilian look at what is suggested before, during, and after an evacuation: https://www.ready.gov/evacuation

Ultimately, depending on the context of the scenario, things will play out slightly differently. Where Godzilla hits first, if the U.S. has some fore warning, etc. I hope this helps.

**Noted page numbers are pdf page numbers, not the direct page numbers at the bottom of the pages.**